# CLI instruction not executed in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, interrupt

I'm writing a **Linux v3.2** kernel module on an **Intel Atom** processor (**x86_64** with 2 cores). I want to disable a specific IRQ number, but I'm having trouble doing so on Linux.

I'm dual-booting **MS-DOS** where I can easily disable interrupts in Intel syntax x86 assembly by communicating directly to the **8259 PIC** chip:

```
CLI                ; disable all interrupts
MOV    DX, 0x21    ; set 8259 ioport address
IN     AL, DX      ; store current interrupt mask in AL
AND    AL, 0xDF    ; modify mask to disable IRQ 5
OUT    DX, AL      ; send new mask to 8259
STI                ; reenable interrupts
```

This works quite well and I'm successfully able to disable specific IRQ numbers.

In **Linux**, I'm aware that I must use `disable_irq` macro to disable interrupts, but it seems to have no effect.

```c
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
...
disable_irq(5);    // disable IRQ 5
```

The `disable_irq` line is at the beginning of my character driver's `open` function. However, while the rest of the code in my `open` function execute as usual when I open my device node, IRQ 5 is left enabled -- it seems like `disable_irq` had no effect at all.

I wasn't sure whether I'm using the `disable_irq` macro correctly, so I decided to try straight inline assembly to verify that my logic is correct. I decided to start simple and first try to disable all interrupts:

```c
__asm__("cli");
```

However, not even this single instruction seems to get executed because all the interrupts are still left enabled.

I'm utterly confused now, why doesn't straight assembly disable the interrupts on **Linux**? What is the correct way to disable interrupts on **Linux**?

---

**UPDATE**: I discovered that `disable_irq` works only if it is executed after a `request_irq`. Is this a bug, or expected behavior?

I found [a thread that seems to vaguely describe the behavior I'm seeing](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/disable_irq_races.html), but it's dated and I'm not sure it's still relevant for my version of Linux.

---

**UPDATE2:**

Here's the kernel module I tried on *Debian* running **Linux v3.2.0-4**:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/irqflags.h> /* Needed for local_irq_disable et al. */

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static unsigned long flags = 0;

static int __init initialization_routine(void)
{
        local_irq_save(flags);
        local_irq_disable();

        /* __asm__("cli"); */
        /* disable_irq(15); */
        return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_routine(void) {
        local_irq_restore(flags);

        /* __asm__("sti"); */
        /* enable_irq(15); */
        return;
}   

module_init(initialization_routine);
module_exit(cleanup_routine);
```

`disable_irq`/`enable_irq` works correctly. I'm not too particularly interested in the plain assembly instructions (it's just odd that they do not work). Moreover, I'm concerned about why `local_irq_disable` has no observable effect on any of the cores -- i.e. IRQ still show up on all cores.

To check for interrupts I run the following command in my terminal:

```
$ watch -d -n 0.5 cat /proc/interrupt
```

Since `disable_irq` and `enable_irq` run perfectly now, I suspect I'm simply forgetting some sort of initialization code or perhaps `local_irq_disable` and related functions are deprecated or do not apply to x86 processors?

Comment: Just a quick check - you are running a kernel that has support for multi-processors (SMP - symmetric multiprocessing) enabled? If so, make sure your code runs on the appropriate (IRQ-processing) core..

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention that the processor does have multiple cores. However, I should expect at least one of the cores to stop processing interrupts after a `cli` instruction, should I not? Yet IRQs are being displayed on all cores under `/proc/interrupts`.

Comment: Try disabling SMP in kernel - build a single-processor setup. Also, take a look at what interrupt-related features of your kernel are enabled - it might have, for instance, already switched the handler to IO-APIC and it's own non-interrupt communication with host CPU. The Linux kernel slowly but surely departs from handling interrupts directly - there are a number of power and load management reasons to offload as much as possible to different, less.. interrupt-y channels.

Comment: @qdot So it could be that the `cli` instruction executes, but has no discernible effects since IO-APIC is now being used? I think that may be it, since the legacy DOS system would only be using a signal core and not be aware of IO-APIC. Does that mean that `disable_irq` also has no effect in this case?

Comment: `disable_irq` should work, but probably only for the current core, which might not be the correct one, since it's primary purpose is to be run at the core that already has the responsibility for this device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is the issue -- I see IRQ 5 continue to go off on all cores even after a `disable_irq(5)` whereas I expect at least one core to have IRQ 5 disabled. Perhaps I have a kernel configuration option set that is turning these `disable_irq` calls to noops.

Comment: @qdot Unless do you mean that there is a specific core which is in charge of sending the interrupts to each of the other cores, and this is the specific core which needs to execute the `disable_irq` for it to have effect?

Comment: How are you checking if interrupts are enabled or not ? /proc/interrupts ? The just display the count of all interrupts on all cpu's that have occurred till that point. I am not sure whether disabling any interrupt would remove it from /proc/interrupt.

Comment: I built a small module to disable interrupt 15 using disable_irq() and it works. IRQ 15 counter stops when the module is loaded and starts incrementing again when I remove my module. I chose IRQ 15 as it was getting incremented for each output of /proc/interrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relation between disable_irq()/enable_irq() to request_irq(). The same is echoed by Linus in the thread whose link you have posted. disable_irq() can be called without registering for that particular irq number. I tested this module to verify the behaviour and it works. Below is the module code I used

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init initialization_routine(void)
{
        disable_irq(15);
        return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_routine(void) {

        enable_irq(15);
        return;
}   

module_init(initialization_routine);
module_exit(cleanup_routine);
```

After loading my module...output of /proc/interrupt

```
15:      68321          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
```

After removing my module...output of /proc/interrupt

```
15:      68325          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
```

I also, experimented using cli and sti assembly instructions instead of disable_irq() and enable_irq(). But loading the module resulted in the below output in dmesg..

```
[root@localhost 5]# dmesg
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 5989 at init/main.c:699 do_one_initcall+0x13e/0x1a0()
initcall initialization_routine+0x0/0x9 [test_module] returned with disabled interrupts 
Modules linked in: test_module(OF+) rfcomm lp bridge bnep 8021q garp stp llc ipt_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables ip6t_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_state nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables ipv6 fuse dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod uinput ppdev parport_pc parport btusb bluetooth rfkill snd_ens1371 snd_rawmidi snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc e1000 microcode sg pcspkr shpchp i2c_piix4 i2c_core ext4(F) jbd2(F) mbcache(F) floppy(F) sd_mod(F) crc_t10dif(F) sr_mod(F) cdrom(F) mptspi(F) mptscsih(F) mptbase(F) scsi_transport_spi(F) pata_acpi(F) ata_generic(F) ata_piix(F) [last unloaded: test_module]
CPU: 1 PID: 5989 Comm: insmod Tainted: GF       W  O 3.11.0-rc2 #5
Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/02/2012
 00000000000002bb ffff8800271b3d38 ffffffff8154516d 00000000000002bb
 ffff8800271b3d88 ffff8800271b3d78 ffffffff8104bf1c ffff8800271b3d68
 0000000000000000 ffffffffa0540000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8154516d>] dump_stack+0x49/0x5c
 [<ffffffff8104bf1c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8c/0xc0
 [<ffffffffa0540000>] ? 0xffffffffa053ffff
 [<ffffffff8104c006>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
 [<ffffffff8126c329>] ? strlcat+0x69/0x80
 [<ffffffffa0540000>] ? 0xffffffffa053ffff
 [<ffffffff8100030e>] do_one_initcall+0x13e/0x1a0
 [<ffffffff81077995>] ? __blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x65/0x80
 [<ffffffff810b43b4>] do_init_module+0x44/0x1b0
 [<ffffffff810b61d2>] load_module+0x5b2/0x6f0
 [<ffffffff810b3b00>] ? __unlink_module+0x30/0x30
 [<ffffffff810b3280>] ? module_sect_show+0x30/0x30
 [<ffffffff810b64d2>] SyS_init_module+0xd2/0x120
 [<ffffffff81551d42>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
---[ end trace 456a5393bc94bdcf ]---
```

This might be due to the fact that I am running Linux on a virtual machine. But none the less, sti and cli instructions should never be used directly inside a kernel module. You should always use kernel API's provided for disabling interrupts on a single core rather than disabling them entirely system wide.

**Edit 1:**

I presume you are running on a x86 machine. local_irq_disable() eventually calls the below function which executes assembly instruction cli. As you have already mentioned that cli/sti are not working on your system, local_irq_disable()/local_irq_enable() won't too.

```
static inline void native_irq_disable(void)
{
        asm volatile("cli": : :"memory");
}
```

Comment: I had been using a kernel patched with Xenomai, but after trying the code on a vanilla kernel, `disable_irq/enable_irq` seem to work fine. However, CLI/STI still seem to produce no effect, and neither does `local_irq_disable/local_irq_enable`. I've updated my original post to include a verbatim copy of my code.

Comment: When u watch the output of /proc/interrupt after loading you module, do the interrupt counters keep incrementing ?

Comment: Yes, all keep incrementing if I use `local_irq_disable`; if I use `disable_irq` for specific IRQs, those do not increment. I tested this on **Linux v3.10** as well and the same behavior is seen -- so I no longer believe it is a bug, but probably a misunderstanding of how `local_irq_disable` is used. Do you get the same behavior on your machine when using `local_irq_disable` as I have?

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your edit. So since we know CLI doesn't seem to work on my machine, this would explain `local_irq_disable` not working either. Furthermore, I suspect that CLI doesn't work since I'm using IOAPIC, so this explains why both CLI and `local_disable_irq` are not working. `disable_irq` is probably interacting correctly with IOAPIC, and thus we see an effect. I think that solves the mystery then! I wonder why they didn't make `local_irq_disable` work like `disable_irq` though.

Answer (score 5):

I happened onto this question.  It's been a year, but not really a good answer yet. I'd like to offer a high-level perspective that seems to be missing about Intel architecture and Linux's architecture.  You can dig into the excellent Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, which Intel shares in PDF form on its website. But here's the information to frame the answer, which is basically, don't try to block a specific vector for all cpus - use spin_locks carefully, and local_irq_disable().

Each processor core has an "interrupt flag" that enables or disables the interruption mechanism on that core only. That's what Linux's local_irq_* routines change (they use the CLI/STI instructions or save, modify, and reload the flags register, changing the IF flag).

Device interrupts are routed to a specific processor core, to its Local APIC (advanced programmable interrupt controller), where an IRQ bit is set for a particular interrupt vector. One of several ways to block a specific interrupt vector from being injected is to set the mask register in the Local APIC (LAPIC) for that core.  It can only be done while actually running on that specific core, which makes it tricky to do unless you know your code is running on that core.  Generally, this mechanism might be useful if used to take care that nested interrupts don't happen.  But the LAPIC can handle the nested interrupt more easily: use the priority masking provided in the LAPIC, since you typically want to block the current interrupt and all lower priority interrupts while running in a handler.  Look at the LAPIC PPR register functionality for this. Generally you won't need to write any code to benefit from this, because Linux's interrupt handling is designed around the PPR mechanism and just works.

In general, I would recommend designing your device driver code in a way that would completely avoid the idea of trying to "disable" an interrupt globally.  There's no easy way to prevent loss of interrupts "in flight" or other disasters. Instead, use the priority mechanism to deal with interrupts in device interrupt handlers, and construct other code with a careful use of spin_lock or spin_lock_irqsave which as a side effect block interrupts on the cpu executing it.

If the interlocking code is short, you should be able to design the device so you spin_lock_irqsave in the device interrupt handler itself, which safely prevents other cores from touching the device during an interrupt, and vice versa.

Now if you really need to have a randomly selected core block the interrupt for other cores, when it is operating outside an interrupt handler, you need to look at how interrupts are actually delivered to a core's LAPIC. I don't know why you would want to do this - most device drivers don't try to do this, but it might be relevant for some device-specific reason.

Interrupts are delivered to LAPICs over a shared interrupt bus, which allows interrupts to be transmitted to one or more LAPICs in a single transaction. (the multicast modes are rarely, if ever, used for devices, so I won't explain them here - see Intel's manual). The shared interrupt bus either sends interrupts to an IOAPIC device or over the Front-Side-Bus directly to a LAPIC, addressed via its APIC ID, and specifying the vector number to be used.  (the FSB mechanism can be used directly by more modern devices - PCI Express and the HPET, but most legacy devices use the IOAPIC.)

To block a specific vector globally across all processors, you can do one of three things, conceptually:  a) reprogram the IOAPIC or PCI Express register that the device uses to set a "mask" bit.  However, that's a lot of stuff, and may require stopping all the other cpu cores that might be getting an interrupt or other magic.  You might use this when starting or stopping the device, once. b) do something with the shared IDT to capture the interrupt temporarily, and then forward it to the right handler later.  This is also complicated and dangerous. c) Change the device state to not generate interrupts at all.  Most devices have the ability to not generate interrupts.

However, one must remember that there may be one or more interrupts "in flight" while trying to do this global suppression.